# Make yasnippet context sensitive

Tags: yasnippet

In LaTeX I often use `pythontex` in a way that there is a block `\begin{pycode}[sessionname]` ... `\end{pycode}` where I make some calculations. Then in the following text I refer to variables defined there for example via `\py[sessionname]{Variable}`.

Now I can make a yas-snippet that expands for example `py` to `\py[]{}`. But then I have to manually insert the session name.

So how can I make a snipped which looks backwards and automatically inserts the session name of the previous `pycode` environment while expanding `py`?

If there is another snipped package which can do this, I am interested in it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by [embedding elisp](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-2).

Here's a quick and dirty function that returns the session name from the last `begin{pycode}` line.

```
(defun my/latex-last-pycode-session ()
  (or (and (re-search-backward "^\\\\begin{pycode}\\[\\(.+\\)\\]\\s-*$" nil t)
           (match-string 1))
      "dunno"))
```

There might be latex-mode functions/variables (e.g., a function that says "am I in a block?") that you could use here, but the above will do to demonstrate how you can get your desired behavior with yasnippet.

Then you can use this function in your snippet:

```
# key: py
# --
\py[`(my/latex-last-pycode-session)`]{$0}
```